# How to access asp.net membership database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

> I`m trying to access default membership database. Because i have added 3 more table. I`m doing this by using entity framework. But it isn`t displaying database name. I want a single database in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting to the ApplicationServices database in your project's App_Data folder?

Or did you create the ApplicationServices database on a genuine SQL Server instance?

In any event:

1. This link can help: http://www.misfitgeek.com/adding-asp-net-membership-to-your-own-database/
2. As always, the connection string will definitively tell you where your database is located.

Answer (score 0):

After you run your project for first time, just go to the `App_Data` Folder and there you can see the database file.
**Remember** to do the following before it:

[image]

You can access by double clicking it..

Comment: I`m trying to access them through code. like
private aspnet db = new aspnet();

Comment: Have you made any change to your connection string to your web.config file?

Comment: after setup a new project, i just shorts its name. After 1st run it showing me its name which i change.

Comment: Try adding something to the database...thus, database will appear in app_data folder. You will be able to see it with above proc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question completely ...
But
Install **SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO** . The **best** official programm for microsoft to connect ,show,edit and update your databases ;-)

[image]

You can through this program have a better visibilitée installed bases.
Otherwise you can simply querying with the console manually using the prefix 
"USE [aspnet_nameTable] ..."

sample:

```
USE [dbo].[aspnet_users]
CREATE DATABASE blablobli......
```

**OR you can attach the local database** in SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO

[image]

Comment: but i`m using local db. below is the connection string.
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Login_DB.mdf;Initial Catalog=Login_DB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Okay, I understand. but you can access to your databases in sql server management studio. With the method attach. See my post updated now